# what is the best way to run shell script (with root privilege) via php?

Tags: php, bash, scripting, permissions

I've made a simple bash script for server admininstration and I cannot figure how can I run it in safely inside a php page: I'd like to create a php admininstration page but I obviously don't want to hard-code root password anyware. Let's make an example (this is a foo script, of course)

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /$1
```

this simple/stupid script will not work if the user who run it as no writing permission on /.
Actually the script add apache virtualhosts, ftp users and so on...
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: This does not sound like something you want to be calling from a web accessible script.

Comment: I'll second Jason's warning.  Unless the script is very carefully written, it's likely that it can be used to do ... unexpected ... things.  Just for example, your sample script could be used to touch password validation files in /var/db/sudo, or touch multiple files (since `$1` is used without double-quotes, if it contains spaces it'll be treated as multiple arguments to `touch`).  Your real script is likely far more complex, which means it'll likely have many more opportunities for mischief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
sudo /path/to/executable/file
```

and set up `sudo` so it can execute the following command for the current user as a root.

http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html - here is the sudoers manual, the configuration file, that you have to modify.

```
zerkms ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables -L FORWARD -n -v -x
```

This is example from my `/etc/sudoers`. Here I allowed to run command `/sbin/iptables -L FORWARD -n -v -x` as `root` without asking a password for user `zerkms`.